# Contact Form How to change sender email

Tags: php, html, forms

How do I make emails generated by this script to send information from the email field as the sender?

I tried to change this code in many ways, but usually it stopped working. As now everything works only that the message generates from kontak@ltdbroker.pl to kontakt@ltdbroker.pl. And I want it to be generated from xxxx@xxx.xx(whatever the user types) to kontakt@ltdbroker.pl Therefore, please, if someone can tell me what to do, I would be grateful

```
<form action="mail.php">

                            <input type="text" placeholder="Imię i Nazwisko" name="Imię" required>
                            <input type="email" placeholder="Email" name="Email" required>
                            <input type="text" placeholder="Temat" name="Temat" required>
                            <textarea name="Message" required placeholder="Wpisz tekst"></textarea>

                            <div class="btn-wrap">
                                <button>Wyślij</button>
                            </div>
                    </form>
```

```
<?php

$method = $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'];

$c = true;
if ( $method === 'POST' ) {

    $project_name = "LtdBroker";
    $admin_email  = "kontakt@ltdbroker.pl";
    $form_subject = "Nowa Wiadomość!";

    foreach ( $_POST as $key => $value ) {
        if ( $value != "" && $key != "project_name" && $key != "admin_email" && $key != "form_subject" ) {
            $message .= "
            " . ( ($c = !$c) ? '<tr>':'<tr style="background-color: #f8f8f8;">' ) . "
            <td style='padding: 10px; border: #e9e9e9 1px solid;'><b>$key</b></td>
            <td style='padding: 10px; border: #e9e9e9 1px solid;'>$value</td>
        </tr>
        ";
    }
}
} else if ( $method === 'GET' ) {

    $project_name = "LtdBroker";
    $admin_email  = "kontakt@ltdbroker.pl";
    $form_subject = "Nowa Wiadomość!";

    foreach ( $_GET as $key => $value ) {
        if ( $value != "" && $key != "project_name" && $key != "admin_email" && $key != "form_subject" ) {
            $message .= "
            " . ( ($c = !$c) ? '<tr>':'<tr style="background-color: #f8f8f8;">' ) . "
            <td style='padding: 10px; border: #e9e9e9 1px solid;'><b>$key</b></td>
            <td style='padding: 10px; border: #e9e9e9 1px solid;'>$value</td>
        </tr>
        ";
    }
}
}

$message = "<table style='width: 100%;'>$message</table>";

function adopt($text) {
    return '=?UTF-8?B?'.Base64_encode($text).'?=';
}

$headers = "MIME-Version: 1.0" . PHP_EOL .
"Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8" . PHP_EOL .
'From: '.adopt($project_name).' <kontakt@ltdbroker.pl>' . PHP_EOL .
'Reply-To: '.$admin_email.'' . PHP_EOL;

mail($admin_email, adopt($form_subject), $message, $headers );
```

Comment: "I want it to be generated from xxxx@xxx.xx(whatever the user types)"....don't do this! Many mailservers will see this as an attempt to spoof the user's identity, in order to send spam or fraud emails on their behalf. So if you do this, it will greatly increase the chances of your mail getting blocked. Instead, make the email come from something like "donotreply@yourdomain.com" where yourdomain.com is the same domain where the mailserver you're using is located. If you need to include the sender's email address, just include it as part of the message body, and/or as a reply-to address

Comment: Thank you for the information, but that's what my boss wants, it is due to the fact that our CRM does not allow you to change the email address to answer.

Comment: "that's what my boss wants"...then it's your duty as a programmer to give your boss the benefit of your professional expertise and explain why it's a bad idea which will make the system unreliable. If you explain carefully and clearly, then you can soon persuade them to change the requirements - they won't want to be responsible for causing problems with emails being delivered. And it'll be even easier if you can simultaneously propose a workable alternative which will do a better job.

Comment: P.S. It's unclear how your CRM system relates to this code? Does the email you send get read automatically by the CRM, you mean? Maybe there is a better way to interface with the CRM - e.g. perhaps it has a web API where you can directly send the contact data, rather than relying on email? If you are just using this to add data to the CRM, then that would be a much better solution, if possible.